# Harmonic Generating Function

Tags: power-series, generating-functions, harmonic-numbers

I have noticed an interesting generating function involving Harmonic Numbers.

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}H_nx^n=\frac{\ln(1-x)}{x-1}$$

But, I have not seen a generating function involving second-order Harmonic numbers, such as

(1) $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}H_n^{(2)}x^n$

(2) $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(H_n^{(2)})^2x^n$

(3) $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(H_n^{(2)})^kx^n$

I was wondering if these generating functions are known, and how can I go about finding them? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You can find a formula on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number#Generalized_harmonic_numbers): $\sum \limits _{n=1} ^\infty H_n ^{(m)} x^n = \frac {\mathrm{Li}_m (z)} {1-z}$, where $\mathrm{Li}_m$ is the [polylogarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm). I doubt that you will be able to find something involving more elementary functions.

Comment: I think that beyond what you answered, there will not be any closed form expression.